# How to remove file type classifier from the 'ls' command output on oh-my-zsh and Mac?

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I suspect this has to do with my `oh-my-zsh` setup on my Mac, but I am not able to figure out. When I do `ls *.sh` on command line, I get something like:

`foo.sh*        bar.sh*`

I understand that by default, `-F` is applied on `ls`:

> -F      Display a slash ('/') immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an asterisk ('*') after each that is executable, an at
>   sign ('@') after each symbolic link, an equals sign ('=') after each
>   socket, a percent sign ('%') after each white-out, and a vertical bar
>   ('|') after each that is a FIFO.

I really want to list the file names without their classifiers. This is desirable because without that, my `for`:

```
for f in `ls *.sh` 
do
wc -l $f
done
```

breaks on executable shell scripts (because of the trailing `*`):

```
wc: foo.sh*: open: No such file or directory 
wc: bar.sh*: open: No such file or directory
```

Of course, I can easily work around this. I just wanted to know if I can take care of it on the output of the `ls` command. Also, this works fine when my shell is `bash`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for discussion of why using `ls` for any other purpose other than generating a list for human viewing is a Bad Idea in general (including on bash; it's also the very first entry in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: Thanks! I agree, the output of `ls` command is _perhaps_ not its "exported interface" (will it ever change?). That aside, in a script, if I can't use glob directly (in a `for` loop like `for f in *.sh`) if those `*.sh` files I want to examine are in a folder other than the script's _cwd_, right? What do we do in such cases (perhaps `cd` to that directory and `cd` back?)

Comment: You absolutely can iterate over files in a different directory. Instead of iterating over `ls -1 "$dir"`, use `for path in "$dir"/*.sh; do`; if you want to get a basename, `file=${path##*/}` will do.

Comment: As for whether the interface will ever change, it varies between platforms already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `ls` in order to generate a list of matching files. You can just use the pattern directly:

```
for f in *.sh
do
    wc -l $f
done
```

This also has the advantage to work with filenames that contain spaces.

Generally speaking: the output of ls is for human consumption, it should never be parsed. Usually file lists can be generated directly with globbing and any information `ls` might provide can be retrieved by other means (e.g. `stat`).

---

That being said:

`-F` is not enabled by default, hence why there is an option for that. I suspect that `ls` is an alias. You can check with

```
whence -v ls
```

While *oh-my-zsh* by default creates an alias to `ls`, `-F` is not part of the settings.

If you just want to use an unmodified `ls` (maybe with different options) you can prepend the `command` precommand modifier:

```
command ls
```

This will run the external command `ls` (usually `/bin/ls`) instead of an alias or a function.

If you want to get rid of `-F` permanently, you can either overwrite it somewhere at the very end of your configuration. Or you track down where it is set and change it there. This command might help in finding where the alias is set:

```
grep -r $(whence ls) ~/.zshrc ~/oh-my-zsh.sh ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

Depending on your setup there might be additional configuration files.

Comment: One might suggest `command ls` as a standards-compliant way to avoid alias or function execution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the suggestion. I added it to the answer.

Comment: cool, thanks! In my case `whence -v ls` produces `ls is an alias for ls -FG`